# как преобразовать аудио файл в текст?

Tags: flutter, dart

Как преобразовать аудио файл в текст? Некий аналог Youtube, когда речь транслируется в текст. Подскажите, может есть такая библиотека на **pub.dev** или статью какую-либо почитать. Буду рад любой информации. Спасибо.

Comment: [speech_recognition](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_recognition)

Comment: Уважаемый InDevX, огромное Вам спасибо, но, скорее всего, это плагин для использования распознавания речи. То есть, из текста в аудио файл, а нужно наоборот, из аудо файла в текст.

Comment: Не за что. Это Вам как подсказка, так сказать. Знаю что у нас на работе этот пакет использовали для конвертации аудио в текст, не записи. Возможно, что-то оттуда взяли и дорабатывали, тут уж не знаю, увы.

Comment: Уважаемый InDevX, еще раз спасибо, буду разбираться.